# How do I multiply an unsigned int by -1 on a SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I need to manipulate an unsigned integer multiplying it by -1.

When I try that it just returns a random value around the maximum representable value.

Comment: Random?  Or `MAX - x + 1`?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of an unsigned int that it can't be negative? Or am I being dumb?

Comment: Yeah, it seems unlikely that the result is *random*. This sounds like it's by design. Either way, I guess you need to cast the result to an unsigned int. Have you tried something like `CAST(fieldname * -1, UNSIGNED)`?

Comment: @StephenTG, you are correct.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that would be the way to do it, ftkg would have to make sure that the number cast were in the range of UNSIGNED, though.    Also, may I ask why you are negating an unsigned int?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, you are right

Comment: @rogaos I am negating an unsigned int because in my current table there's an extra column determining whether the int is 'positive' or 'negative'. Not good design, but I'll have to live with it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the result in the query.

```
SELECT CAST( fieldname * -1 AS SIGNED ) FROM ...
-- or
SELECT CONVERT ( fieldname * -1, SIGNED ) FROM ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting the negative of the value in your unsigned int variable, you will not get it, because the datatype is **unsigned**. It can only holde +ve values.

For datatype *int*: The signed range is -2147483648 to 2147483647. The unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295.

The multiplication by -1 would have happened, and the result will also be of the same datatype (unsigned int), whose MSB (most significant bit) will be 1 to represent the negative-ness.

Convert or Cast the result to a signed int to get what you want.